# Elasticsearch Partial Fields With Inner Hits

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use the `partial_fields` parameter when performing a `nested` filter/query ?

For example this query will return just the fields I am looking for from the `hits`:

```
{
  "query": {
      "filtered": {
          "query": {
              "ids": {
                  "type": "users",
                  "values": [
                      "111"
                  ]
              }
          },
          "filter": {
              "nested": {
                  "path": "entitlements",
                  "filter": {
                      "bool": {
                          "must": [
                              {
                                  "term": {
                                    "program": "program-a"
                                  }
                              }
                         ]
                      }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {
                      "size": 999
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "partial_fields": {
      "partial": {
          "include": [
              "entitlements.accountNumber",
              "entitlements.name",
              "entitlments.numbers"
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

However the `inner_hits` section, no fields are returned.

```
   "inner_hits": {
           "entitlements": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 1,
                 "max_score": 1,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "myGreatIndex",
                       "_type": "users",
                       "_id": "111",
                       "_nested": {
                          "field": "entitlements",
                          "offset": 0
                       },
                       "_score": 1,
                       "fields": {
                          "partial": [
                             {}
                          ]
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
```

Is there a way to apply this for `inner_hits` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside the `inner_hits` section, you may use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) instead. `partial_fields` will work for outer hits and `_source` for `inner_hits`.

So you can specify your `inner_hits` like this:

```
"inner_hits": {
    "size": 999,
    "_source": [
          "accountNumber",
          "name",
          "numbers"
    ]
}
```

Note, though, that within your `inner_hits` results, you'll still get an empty `partial` array, but the fields you need will show up within the `_source` section.

Also worth noting that if you specify your `partial_fields` with unqualified names (see below), then partial fields will show up in your `inner_hits` results, but **not** in the outer hits anymore. So you need to figure out which works best for you.

```
"partial_fields": {
   "partial": {
     "include": [
        "accountNumber",
        "name",
        "numbers"
     ]
   }
}
```